# How can I avoid using the div style for one element and use it for other element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm sorry if I'm not asking it properly. But this is my html file:

```
<div class = "fade-it" style="color:rgb(85, 23, 23)">
    <marquee behavior="scroll" scrollamount="4" direction="right">
        <h2 footer id="msg"></h2>
        <h2 footer id="no-fade"></h2>
    </marquee>
</div>
```

I have two h2 elements in this div. when the element id = "msg", I want to use the style of the class "fade it", I don't wanna use that style when the h2 element id is "no-fade". how can I avoid the css style of the div when the element ID = "no-fade" even though it's in same div?

Comment: You mean a selector like `.fade-it h2#msg`…?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee I'd probably consider using a different method for making your text scroll than using the `marquee` element.

Comment: Inline styles have the highest specificity. Use a class. Ids have more specificity than classes. Just use a class and stylize the id.

Comment: Let the `.fade-it` class fade as is without any additional code changes. Then give `.no-fade` a position absolute and position it with left and right. `#no-fade {position:absolute; top: 100px left: 100px }`. In case you don't know this I will tell it to you now immediately after this sentence and beginning the following sentence. If you make the parent, grandparent, greatgrandparent, etc. position:relative then the position absolute element will be positioned relative to *it*.